# Fresnel gradient shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, effects

I've tried my hardest to try and replicate this style, but can't for the life of me get anywhere near it. Is anyone able to get close to this style?

[image]

Comment: Hi Oliver, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like a frosted glass shader to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get nice results using the *Layer Weight* node.

1. Mix two glass shaders. One with IOR=1 (no refraction), other with high IOR
2. *Layer Weight - Facing* to drive the mix shader
3. Use *Color Ramp* to control the edge effect

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: amazing! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey, me again! trying to replicate what you've done and it's not working for me. Could you possibly send over a blend file so I can troubleshoot?

Comment: @OliverPrimus Sure thing, I added the .blend :)

Comment: you are the best! Thanks so much!