# How to create a feathered border around an object?

Tags: shaders, masking

This is the best way I could possibly phrase this question.

What I want to do is mix two different materials.

I want to use the *secondary material* to catch the rimlight of the object, but I only want this effect to show up **close to the border of an object.**

Simply using the angles of the faces will result in **too much spill** of the *secondary material* over the *primary material*. This only works on a simple object, where the falloff angle of the polygons is even.

Is there a way to create a mask within the shader editor to basically create a blurred outline within the object border? **I want to avoid using the compositor for this.**

[image: Using a layer weight node affects all angled surfaces, which is less than ideal.]

[image: This is the kind of result that I am looking for.]

Comment: Related: [How do I make a glass texture with an outline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177613/78972), [Fresnel gradient shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/176031/78972)

Answer (score 0):

You might set transparancy based upon camera facing normals (ea not facing). (layer weight)
To get something that looks a little bit smoother.

Comment: Yes, this is what I tried. I went through several iterations to get close. But this is not the way to create a border to overlay on the edges of the object alpha. But thanks!

Comment: You could also try spherical texture based upon object location offset by a vector. Then use that to drive a color ramp and set alpha. And maybe combine (multiply) values to drive a mix shader

Comment: Another thing that might work for you there is an edge input.

Comment: And a 3th to try put some bump noice to make it less black